# how to store & read arbitrary url inside Input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

i have the following inside my asp.net mvc view:-

```
<input type="submit" id="addswitch" data-targeturl="@Url.Action("showSwitches","Rack")" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" value="Add">
```

the idea is that i need to store the realted URL insdie an arbitrary value which i name it data-targeturl.

then inside my script , which will fire when the user clicks on the above input field as follow:-

```
 $('body').on("click", "#addserver,#addsd,#addfirewall,#addrouter,#addswitch", function () {




         $("#showAddDialog").dialog({
             title: "Add Exsisting " + dialogtitle,
             width: 'auto', // overcomes width:'auto' and maxWidth bug
             maxWidth: 600,
             height: 'auto',
             modal: true,
             fluid: true, //new option
             resizable: false

         });
          var URL = this.data-targeturl;
```

but currently i am getting the following error:-

```
ReferenceError: targeturl is not defined


var URL = this.data-targeturl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) or [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```
var URL = $(this).data("targeturl"); 
//OR 
//var URL = this.dataset.targeturl;
```

instead of

```
var URL = this.data-targeturl
```

Comment: ok worked well, thanks,, now my question is if it is valid approach to have arbitrary values stored inside an input field ?

Comment: @johnG, As per your example, its perfectly fine

Comment: so what type of arbitrary values i should store ? let say that i need to show a dialog box when the user clicks on the above input field, and i want the dialog to have a dynamic title, so is it semantically valid to have another arbitrary values inside my input field named data-dialogtitle="this is my title!!"??

Comment: @johnG, Yes that's fine